# How to change default discount in python using classes and inheriance?

Tags: python, class, oop, inheritance, attributes

I was trying to change the discount rate of a particular sub class, while the default is set at 0, and in subclass it changes to 5, however, this is not refelected.

I cannot switch the discount scheme on Class B, because all class need to have access on it.

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, x, y, discount=0):
        self.discount=0
        if self.discount>0:
            discount = self.discount
        else:
            discount=0
        self.discount=discount
        self.x=x
        self.y=y
        self.discount=discount
        discount=5
class B(A):
    def __init__ (self,x,y,z):
        super().__init__(x,y)
        B.z=z
        B.discount=5
        
class C(A):
    def __init__ (self,x,y,a):
        super().__init__(x,y) 
        C.a=a
        C.discount = 10
        a = y*10

one=A(1,2)
print(one.x)
print(one.discount)
two = B(1,2,3)
print(two.x)
print(two.z)
print(two.discount)
three = C(4,5,6)
print(three.x)
print(three.discount)
```

Output:

```
1
0
1
3
0
4
0
```

Tried to do some calculations and integrate methods, but it only works for methoid but not on the class, as you can see, the discount is set to 0 and doesn't change.

Comment: Hint: where the code says `self.discount=0` within `class A`, exactly what do you think this means? What would it mean that's **different**, if this instead said `A.discount = 0`? Next: where the code says `B.discount=5`, exactly what do you think this means? What would it mean that's **different**, if this instead said `self.discount = 5`? (Hint: isn't this the same situation the other way around?) Finally: where the code says `print(two.discount)`, where do you think Python will look **first** to find `discount` - in the object, or in the class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The constructor of your `A` class seems quite confusing. If the only thing you need is to check if the `discount` parameter is greater than `0` and set it to your instance's `discount` variable, you can simplify your code like this:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, x, y, discount=0):
        self.discount=0
        if discount>0:
            self.discount = discount
        self.x=x
        self.y=y
```

Moreover, when you try to modify an instance variable in a subclass, you can still use `self`:

```
class B(A):
    def __init__ (self,x,y,z):
        super().__init__(x,y)
        self.z=z
        self.discount=5
        
class C(A):
    def __init__ (self,x,y,a):
        super().__init__(x,y) 
        self.a=a
        self.discount = 10
        a = y*10
```

Running the commands again, you 'll get:

```
1
0
1
3
5
4
10
```

You can find more about instance and class variables [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-and-instance-variables) and inheritance [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#inheritance).